# Copy Azure Blob as BlockBlob from Remote URL

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-python

I'm using the [azure-sdk-for-python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python) `BlobClient` `start_copy_from_url` to copy a remote file to my local storage.

However, the file always ends up as an AppendBlob instead of BlockBlob. I can't see how I can force the destination BlockType to be BlockBlob.

```
connection_string = "connection string to my dest blob storage account"
container_name = "myContainerName"
dest_file_name = "myDestFile.csv"
remote_blob_url = "http://path/to/remote/blobfile.csv"

client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
dest_blob = client.get_blob_client(container_name, dest_file_name)
dest_blob.start_copy_from_url(remote_blob_url)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't change blob type as soon as you create it.Please see the [Copy Blob From URL REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-blob-from-url),no `blob-types` header.

You could refer to my code to create block blob from append blob:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobPermissions
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
import requests
from io import BytesIO

account_name = "***"
account_key = "***"
container_name = "test"
blob_name = "test2.csv"

block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name, account_key)

sas_token = block_blob_service.generate_blob_shared_access_signature(container_name, blob_name,
                                                                     permission=BlobPermissions.READ,
                                                                     expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1))
blob_url_with_sas = block_blob_service.make_blob_url(container_name, blob_name, sas_token=sas_token)

r = requests.get(blob_url_with_sas, stream=True)
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_stream("test", "jay.block", stream=BytesIO(r.content))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you want to do using the latest version (v12)
According [to the documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/azure/storage/blob/_blob_client.py#L1261-L1263),

> The source blob for a copy operation may be a block blob, an append blob,
>           or a page blob. If the destination blob already exists, it must be of the
>           same blob type as the source blob.

Right now, you cannot use start_copy_from_url to specify a blob type. However, you can use the synchronous copy APIS to do so in some cases.

For example, for block to page blob, create the destination page blob first and invoke `update_range_from_url` on the destination, with each chunk of 4 MB from the source.

Similarly, in your case, create an empty block blob first and the use the [`stage_block_from_url` method](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/azure/storage/blob/_blob_client.py#L1663).

```
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient
import os

conn_str = os.getenv("AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING")
dest_blob_name = "mynewblob"
source_url = "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/59466/59466-0.txt"

container_client = ContainerClient.from_connection_string(conn_str, "testcontainer")

blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(dest_blob_name)
# upload the empty block blob
blob_client.upload_blob(b'')

# this will only stage your block
blob_client.stage_block_from_url(block_id=1, source_url=source_url)
# now it is committed
blob_client.commit_block_list(['1'])

# if you want to verify it's committed now
committed, uncommitted = blob_client.get_block_list('all')
assert len(committed) == 1
```

Let me know if this doesn't work.

EDIT:
You can leverage the `source_offset` and `source_length` params to upload blocks in chunks.
For example,

`stage_block_from_url(block_id, source_url, source_offset=0, source_length=10)`

will upload the first 10 bytes i.e. bytes from 0 to 9.
So, you can use a counter to keep incrementing the block_id and track your offset and length till you exhaust all your chunks.

EDIT2:

```
for step in range(....):
    ###
    blob.stage_block_from_url(...)
    ##do not commit it##
#outside the for loop
blob.commit_block_list([j for j in range(i+1)]) (#or i+2?)
```

Comment: I get the error: The source request body for copy source is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit (100MB). FYI the file is 1.3GB

Comment: Did you try staging blocks with 4 mb chunks?  Let me check something.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block-from-url#remarks

Put Block From URL uploads a block for future inclusion in a block blob. A block blob can include a maximum of 50,000 blocks. Each block can be a different size, up to a maximum of 100 MB. The maximum size of a block blob is therefore slightly more than 4.75 TB (100 MB X 50,000 blocks).

This means, you have to upload your blob in 100 mb chunks if you are using any synchronous copy APIS

Comment: look at the EDIT

Comment: I've created a loop to iterate over the blocks. I have a bug somewhere. It shows an upload of all 1.3 GB but only 4.8 MB ends up in storage.

Comment: Here is the updated code. I don't want to change the original question. https://gist.github.com/briglx/66b2c478ab531bf3d9fd123cafaa967e

Comment: You want to commit all the blocks at once. In the for loop, just stage the blocks and commit all of them at once outside the loop. look at the edit

Comment: Fails when staging blocks get over 100MB before committing them.

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is no direct conversion between blob types. To do this you need to download the blob and reupload it as Block Blob.