# Copy files within Azure ADLS gen2 using Azure CLI, Rest API or Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-lake-gen2

is there any simple way to copy data within Azure ADLS gen2 using Azure CLI, Rest API or Python?

Azure ADLS gen2 API documentation is very limited for now...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/data-lake-storage-gen2

Comment: Having same issue here

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, we can use Azure CLI or python to move a directory or move a file. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-cli).

For example

1. Install the storage CLI extension. Please note that the CLI version should be larger than 2.0.67

```
az extension add -n storage-preview
```

2. Script

```
# move directory
az storage blob directory move -c my-file-system -d my-new-directory -s my-directory --account-name mystorageaccount

# move a file
az storage blob move -c my-file-system -d my-file-new.txt -s my-file.txt --account-name mystorageaccount
```

Python

```
try:

       file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="my-file-system")
       directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client("my-directory")

       new_dir_name = "my-directory-renamed"
       directory_client.rename_directory(rename_destination=directory_client.file_system_name + '/' + new_dir_name)

    except Exception as e:
     print(e)
```

Comment: Thanks, what library do you use in your python example?

Comment: @fuggy_yama  Regarding python sdk, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python

Comment: @fuggy_yama Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: @fuggy_yamaf since you have no other concerns, could you please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). It may help more people.

Comment: I just realized that  it is MOVE operation and I actuall need COPY files within ADLS gen2.

Comment: @JoshD As far as I knew, azure data lake gen2 python sdk does not provide copy function. But the gen2 is based on blob, we can use python blob sdk to implement it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500935/python-how-to-move-or-copy-azure-blob-from-one-container-to-another

Comment: @fuggy_yama did you find anything useful?

Comment: @anidev711 see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58940560/4496488

Comment: This solution MOVES a directory via renaming it. The question is asking about how to COPY data from one directory to another